# Django Rest Framework object level permissions issue while creating an object through POST

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

My files are as follows:

**`BusinessActionsPermission`**

```
class BusinessActionsPermission(BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        business_obj = view.get_business_obj()
        if request.method in ['GET']:
            return request.user.has_perm('act_on_business', business_obj)
        if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']:
            return request.user.has_perm('act_on_business', business_obj)
        return False
```

**`EmployeeViewSet`**

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, BusinessActionsPermission)

    def get_business_obj(self, **kwargs):
        return Business.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['business_id'])

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return Employee.objects.filter(business__id=self.kwargs['business_id'])

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        business = Business.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['business_id'])
        employee = Employee(business=business)
        serializer = EmployeePOSTSerializer(employee, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

The `BusinessActionsPermission` is not working while `POST` method is called to create a new `Employee` through `EmployeeViewSet`. A user without `act_on_busienss` is able to `post` and create an employee.

Django Rest Framework Documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#limitations-of-object-level-permissions) says:

> For performance reasons the generic views will not automatically apply object level permissions to each instance in a queryset when returning a list of objects.

which is fine. As the `BusinessActionsPermission` is working for `detailed retrievals with pk`. But not working on `post` which is not a `list`.

Please help.

**Note**: The `BusinessActionsPermission` above is perfectly working fine for detailed view and doesn't check on list view, which is perfectly fine as mentioned in the docs. But what about `post`??

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of ModelViewSet and generics in rest_framework, you can find out when the object's permission is checked.

The method of BusinessActionsPermission  `has_object_permission` is called when object is retrieved using `get_object` method of `GenericAPIView` class.

So, with this knowledge, we can see that in your case this method is not called when creating new object.

What you need to do is to move the logic from `has_object_permission` to `has_permission`.

You can use `has_object_permission` to check permission for specific object which has been already created ( like ownership for example).